# Unable to call MySQL Stored Procedure from Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm having issues calling a stored procedure from command line. It works absolutely fine from Workbench, but the same SQL executed from command line (where I want to call it using a bash script in cron on a regular basis) just spits out an error.

Here's what I'm executing in Workbench:

```
CALL hourly_summary('20150309',04);
```

Which runs fine.

Here's what I'm executing from CLI:

```
$ mysql -h <REMOVED> -u <REMOVED> -p<REMOVED> netflow -e "CALL hourly_summary('20150309',04);"
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

I've tried fiddling with putting different quotes around the query, and I've also tried going into MySQL CLI and it still fails.

```
$ mysql -h <REMOVED> -u <REMOVED> -p<REMOVED> netflow
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3654
Server version: 5.6.22-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CALL hourly_summary('20150309',04);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
mysql> exit
Bye
```

I don't know what's different between running it in Workbench and from CLI?

The 04 is intentionally not between single quotes. It's an integer in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

what's the content of your procedure? i think something is bad there

btw, referring the the last answer, sqlcmd is an mssql thing

Answer (score -1):

unable to call sp from command line?

```
sqlcmd -E -S server_name -d database_name -Q "EXEC schema.spname param1, param2"
```

try this this may work

Comment: I don't have that command available (and Googling it doesn't come up with anything MySQL related). I think it's for MSSQL only?